# Is there a way to have a computed property for optionals in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve a computed property on an optional, which won't require unwrapping or default value. For the sake of the example, imagine the following scenario:

We have a subclass of UITextField and we want to add some sort of a validation. Let's say if there is a value or not (again, this is for the sake of the example). Right now the way to do so is:

```
var hasValue: Bool {
    if let value = text {
        return value.isEmpty
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I've tried searching through the [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/optionalchaining/) , but I was not able to find such thing. Does anyone have some more elegant solution to this? :)

Comment: `text?.isEmpty ?? false` Or something like that? If the computed value is not optional, but the var you calculated it with is, you'll need an unwrap and a default value anyway...

Comment: "Right now the way to do so is..." What exactly is wrong with this way?

Comment: But in your case, for readability, I'd write it like this: `guard let value = text else { return false } return value.isEmpty`

Comment: Why not simply [`hasText`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext)?

Comment: I don't say there is something wrong about it. I was only trying to give more context about what exactly I am searching for. 
@Sulthan 's answer is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
   var hasValue: Bool {
       return !(self ?? "").isEmpty
   }
}
```

However, in general I would avoid adding such methods because they hide the fact that a variable is optional. I would rather use the `(text ?? "").isEmpty` explicitly.

Comment: I agree about the hiding of the optional, but I still think in some very niche scenarios this could have usage, although it has potential to. Anyway, your answer is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks, mate! :)